# Setting the date format in Atlassian Crucible

Tags: crucible

When I set up a review in Atlassian Crucible, and I set a date, it displays it in DD/MM/YYYY 
I'd like to switch that over to MM/DD/YYYY, but I don't see anywhere in the configuration to switch that.
The closest setting I see is for the timezone, which I have set to EST.

I have Crucible running on a CentOS 6.2 machine that's set to UTC
I'm using Crucible version 2.7.14 Build:20120612060728 2012-06-12

My locale is currently set to en_US.UTF-8

```
> locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Can someone point out how I can switch the date format in Crucible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [JIRA CRUC-1941](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CRUC-1941) they have not implemented this yet.

**Update**: closed as "Won't Fix".

Comment: Wow.  That tickets been open for over 2 years.  
I'm not getting any warm fuzzies from Atlassian.

Comment: seems like Atlassian have decided they can't be bothered implementing that, the ticket has been closed ('WON'T FIX') :-(